# same python source code on two different machines yield different behavior

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

Two machines, both running Ubuntu 14.04.1.  Same source code run on the same data.  One works fine, one throws codec decode 0xe2 error.  Why is this?  (More importantly, how do I fix it?)

Offending code appears to be:

```
def tokenize(self):
    """Tokenizes text using NLTK's tokenizer, starting with sentence tokenizing"""
    tokenized=''
    for sentence in sent_tokenize(self):
        tokenized += ' '.join(word_tokenize(sentence)) + '\n'

    return Text(tokenized)
```

OK...  I went into interactive mode and imported sent_tokenize from nltk.tokenize on both machines.  The one that works was happy with the following:

```
>>> fh = open('in/train/legal/legal1a_lm_7.txt')
>>> foo = fh.read()
>>> fh.close()
>>> sent_tokenize(foo)
```

The UnicodeDecodeError on the machine with issues gives the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 82, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1270, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1318, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1309, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1348, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 355, in _pair_iter
    for el in it:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1324, in _slices_from_text
    if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1369, in text_contains_sentbreak
    for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1504, in _annotate_second_pass
    for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 354, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 621, in _annotate_first_pass
    for aug_tok in tokens:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 586, in _tokenize_words
    for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Breaking the input file down line by line (via split('\n')), and running each one through sent_tokenize leads us to the offending line:

```
If you have purchased these Services directly from Cisco Systems, Inc. (“Cisco”), this document is incorporated into your Master Services Agreement or equivalent services agreement (“MSA”) executed between you and Cisco.
```

Which is actually:

```
>>> bar[5]
'If you have purchased these Services directly from Cisco Systems, Inc. (\xe2\x80\x9cCisco\xe2\x80\x9d), this document is incorporated into your Master Services Agreement or equivalent services agreement (\xe2\x80\x9cMSA\xe2\x80\x9d) executed between you and Cisco.'
```

Update:  both machines show UnicodeDecodeError for:

```
unicode(bar[5])
```

But only one machine shows an error for:

```
sent_tokenize(bar[5])
```

Comment: Please show us the code that throws the exception, as well as input data that triggers it and the full traceback.

Comment: You'll still need to include the traceback and sample data.

Comment: edited for code snippet.  the whole project is in Tk, so I'll try to chase down traceback, but it may take some time.  After looking at the snippet, I'm wondering if changing the strings to unicode (u' ' & u'\n') might not be a good idea...

Comment: No, because those bytestrings can safely be decoded to Unicode with the ASCII codec. If you have a decode error you have *other* bytestrings with non-ASCII bytes.

Comment: Maybe we can take nltk out of the picture. Does `unicode(open('in/train/legal/legal1a_lm_7.txt'))` show the problem?

Comment: @tdelaney - No, that works fine. However, if I loop over the lines and do print x, unicode(x), I see that it's position 72 of the line at the bottom of the edited question causing trouble

Comment: The file is in utf-8, but the only characters outside of the 0-127 range are the curly quotes. Maybe just opening the file with the right codec will do it: `codecs.open('in/train/legal/legal1a_lm_7.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')`.

Comment: Indeed, running sent_tokenize() on the unicode version of that string works fine.  Irritating that the older version was more forgiving than the latest version, though.

Comment: It's an interesting problem for sure and highlights the risk of just casting strings to unicode in python 2.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different NLTK versions!

The version that doesn't barf is using NLTK 2.0.4; the version throwing an exception is 3.0.0.

NLTK 2.0.4 was perfectly happy with

```
sent_tokenize('(\xe2\x80\x9cCisco\xe2\x80\x9d)')
```

NLTK 3.0.0 needs unicode (as pointed out by @tdelaney in the comments above).  So to get results, you need:

```
sent_tokenize(u'(\u201cCisco\u201d)')
```